# How to prevent date-picker popup on initial page load

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I am using jquery for date picker.It always popup when page loading or refresh. How to stop the automatic popup of date picker and the date picker only appear when the text box clicked.
Here is my coding

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">       <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dob" class="form-control" placeholder="DOB" autocomplete="off" required>
        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

date picker script:

```
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pikaday.js"></script>

    <script>

    var picker = new Pikaday(
    {
        field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date(1950, 0, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
        yearRange: [1950, 2020],
        bound: true,


    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the input field and initialize the date picker only when the input field is clicked as shown below :

```
    var dateField = document.getElementById('datepicker');
    dateField.addEventListener("click", function(){
      // Initialize datepicker only when datefile is clicked
      var picker = new Pikaday(
      {
        field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date(1950, 0, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
        yearRange: [1950, 2020],
      });
    });
```

Reference on pikaday : http://dbushell.github.io/Pikaday/

A working example on JSFiddle is : https://jsfiddle.net/d3pzt1ga/

Comment: it's correct what i am want but it not disappear after the selection of date from datepicker

Comment: Remove the bound : true, from the array while initializing. I have edited my answer, have a look

Comment: okey it's work fine now..!!now the date pick doesn't pick more then one time.First we pick the date it work fine again without reloading the page try to pick the date the datepicker exist but it not allow to pick the date..and also it not disappear

Comment: I have attached a JSFiddle of a working example on my answer please go through it. https://jsfiddle.net/d3pzt1ga/

Answer (score 0):

Set  `bound: false,` or add a input before the datepiker so the datepiker isn't focused

Comment: when give bound:false it always stable.when page load or click inside the page